# Can I be a "Teaching Fellow" outside of the UK?

Tags: career-path, teaching

In the UK, a Teaching Fellow is a job position which has the same basic salary level of a postdoc, but allows permanent contracts and increases of salary because of seniority or important duties and responsibilities in the Department.

This means that in the UK, if someone is not too ambitious from a research point of view, and wants to stay in the Academy without the effort of doing research, they can still work just as teachers. They usually have a lower salary, but in the UK it's still more than enough to live a good life, and as I said it can also increase with time.

I was wondering, is this job position only in the UK? And in particular, are there equivalent positions in any of the following countries?

- Italy
- Switzerland
- Austria
- France

I am not sure whether I am just not finding equivalent positions because I don't know the related traditional terminology in those countries, or because this kind of position doesn't exist in those country at all.

The reason why I ask is because I would be interested in a career with academic level teaching, but without the stress of research. I already have this position in the UK, but I would like to live in a different area of Europe, let's say in countries between the Mediterranean and the Alps.

Comment: How fluent are you in the various languages in that region?

Comment: @JonCuster Italian is my native language, and I am also quite good with French, and if the university is international and teaching is in English (for example in some Swiss universities), then I can teach in English too. I cannot teach in German unfortunately, so my only hope for German-speaking regions (like Austria or part of Switzerland) is to teach in universities where lectures are given in English.

Comment: Various places, like https://www.eui.eu/en/home, have some overviews of positions.

Comment: My impression is that the expectations of staff in terms of research and teaching are not necessarily homogeneous across those countries, nor even across different classes of institution within those countries.